# How detect my std::function is still available?

Tags: c++, c++11

Im using std::function and std::bind for my async thread callback system.
but sometimes my system delete my object even some threads are not done.
here some example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Character {
public:
    Character() { a = 10; }

    void Print() { cout << a << endl; }

private:
    int a;

};

void main() {
    Character* pChar = new Character();

    std::function<void()> callback = std::bind(&Character::Print, pChar);
    callback(); // it's fine

    delete pChar;


    callback(); // fail


    if (callback)   // this if doesn't work
        callback();

    // i want to check callback is still available
}
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: You have "delete pChar;" before the second call of callback. At this time you don't have a valid "pChar" object. And please use smart pointers (unique_ptr or share_ptr, depending on your needs).

Comment: The issue is not that the callback is "unavailable" - you are passing/storing an invalid pointer for your `std::function`. You need validate the pointer before calling the callback (which is easier to do using smart pointers)

Comment: thank you all. but I can't vouch call sequence because it's multi thread callback. that example code is just reproduce my program sequence when thread is slow. so I want to know this. if the caller was deleted before callback thread is done, how do I know that?

Comment: Have you tried using std::mem_fn instead. It requires caller to provide a valid object instance upon calling, so you can just check it explicitly before the call. Downside is you will have to propagate the object pointer everywhere, but this seems to be the small price to pay for code correctness.

Comment: What is your goal: Do you want to keep the char object alive until the callback is finished or only execute the callback if, if all data is still alive (assuming no concurrent deletion can happen while the callback is executed)?

Comment: both can help me. but I think "execute the callback when character is deleted" is better @MikeMB

Comment: You can also just dump the std::function idea at all and use the battle-tested observer pattern. (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of an raw pointer, you may use `std::weak_ptr`, something like:

```
void safePrint(std::weak_ptr<Character> w)
{
    auto pChar = w.lock();
    if (pChar) {
        pChar->Print();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto pChar = make_shared<Character>();

    auto callback = std::bind(&safePrint, std::weak_ptr<Character>(pChar));
    callback(); // it's fine

    pChar.reset(); 

    callback(); // won't print, and don't crash :)
}
```

Comment: you mean callback() in last line won't work even Print() accesses Character's member variable or member function? I'll try this right away THANK YOU :)

Comment: When `callback` is called, with `auto pChar = w.lock();`, you retrieve the "correct" value of `pChar` (`nullptr` in second case).

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are deleting `pChar*` pointer which is used in your `callback()` method. Delete `pChar` after you are done with everything.

Comment: This does not answer the question - OP is very much aware of this causing the problem, so they are asking how to detect if they can still call the `std::function` (the object is still available)